# Finding netid in CIDR

Tags: cidr

I am practicing questions related to CIDR and I have come across a particular question which I need some explanation. Can somebody please explain in detail how to answer this question.

An address space, allocated to a site via CIDR, extends from `110.45.232.0` to `110.45.233.255`. What is the netid of the site network indicated by the prefix?

```
[A] 110.45.232.0/21
[B] 110.45.232.0/23
[C] 110.45.2320/24
[D] 110.45.233.0/24
```

Comment: Look for the common prefix length of all those addresses in binary.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all about IPv4 addressing and subnetting.

Answer (score 1):

For your address

- You can have **512 address in your subnet..**
- Your address ranging from 110.45.232.0 to 110.45.233.255
- Your subnet mask will be **255.255.254.0**

> Answer is **110.45.232.0/23 (C)**
>
> - Always find the IP Address range,
> - Check for its classes..
> - Convert the subnet mask into binaries